# submitting params with form_tag to update method gives undefined route error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form like this:

```
= form_tag item_path(@item) do
  # some inputs
```

This gives following HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="/items/1" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <!-- some inputs -->
</form>
```

When I submit it - I get a following error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/items/1"
```

However when I use SimpleForm for the same item - HTML is almost the same and it works:

```
# code:
= simple_form_for @item do |f|
  ...
# output:
<form id="edit_item_1" novalidate="novalidate" method="post" action="/items/1" accept-charset="UTF-8">
...
```

Do you see any mistakes in my code?

How do I make sure that my form_tag submits params to the item update method?

Comment: Please show us the routes for your `ItemsController` too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure why simple_form_for works. But normally Rails form_tag methods generates form with http method POST.

```
<form method="post"
```

So in your case if you want to submit the form to update method then http method should be PUT. You can explicitly specify the http method in rails form_tag.

```
form_tag item_path(@item), :method => :put do |f|
```

Normally people will always prepare form_for instead of form_tag and they will reuse the form template for create and update. Because form_for will set correct http method based on record status.If the record is new it will set the http method to POST else PUT.

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the path in your routes.rb file?

```
resources :items, only: :create
```

or `post "/items/:id" => "items#create"`

I suggest the first one

Comment: Well, it's RESTful.. It's defined as `resources :items`. Shouldn't it already include the update routing?

Comment: When you want a list of routes available you can always run rake routes from the commandline.